# Переклад слова "расплескался"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

В російській мові є таке слово *"расплескался"*.
В тлумачному словнику Ушакова:

> РАСПЛЕСКА́ТЬСЯ, расплещусь, расплещешься, и (разг.) расплескаюсь, расплескаешься, совер. (к расплескиваться.
>
> 1. Плещась, пролиться через край, разлиться по какому-нибудь пространству. Вода из ведра расплескалась. «Море вдруг всколыхалося вокруг, расплескалось в шумном беге.» Пушкин.
> 2. Начав плескаться, увлечься (разг. фам.). Дети в купальне расплескались.

Як перекласти це слово українською? Чи існує лише *"розливатися", "розлитися"*?

Comment: Для початку - який з цих двох смислів вам потрібен?

Comment: -1 за те, що запитання не поправлене відповідно до попереднього коментаря.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова «плескати», «плескатися», «розплескати», «розплескатися», «розпліскувати», «розпліскуватися» є цілком українськими словами.

Зокрема вони є в словниках:

- Б. Грінченка (1909): «росплі́скувати», «росплі́скуватися», «росплеска́ти», «росплеска́тися», «поросплі́скувати» (увага: за сучасним правописом «роз-», а не «рос-»).
- А. Ніковського (1927): «розплі́скувати», «розплі́скуватися», «розплеска́ти», «розплеска́тися».
- Г. Голоскевича (1929): «розплі́скувати», «розплеска́ти».
- СУМ-11 (1970-і): «розплі́скувати», «розплі́скуватися», «розпле́скувати», «розпле́скуватися», «розплеска́ти», «розплеска́тися».

Врешті-решт, маємо ж ми слова «плескати», «оплески» тощо.

Слід зазначити, що також ці слова мають ще одне значення: робити пласким, сплющувати (метал при ковці).

Answer (score 2):

*"РАСПЛЕСКА́ТЬСЯ"* в значені *"1. Плещась, пролиться через край"* можна перекласти як **розхлюпуватись**

> РОЗХЛЮ́ПУВАТИ, ую, уєш, недок., РОЗХЛЮ́ПАТИ, аю, аєш, док., перех. Хлюпаючи, розливати, розбризкувати що-небудь

http://sum.in.ua/s/rozkhljupuvaty

а в значенні *"2. Начав плескаться, увлечься"* - **розхлюпотітись**

> ХЛЮПОТА́ТИ, очу, очеш і ХЛЮПОТІ́ТИ, очу, отиш, недок. Підсил. до хлюпати.  Надворі все ще лляв дощ і було холодно. В черевиках було мокро, хлюпотіла вода

http://sum.in.ua/s/khljupotaty